# Is there a way to automate the below code in Python - Beginner

Tags: python, pandas

In the code below Ive been extracting the top ten non-profits based on Income from each state, putting them into a variable and then merging everything into a new list. In order for me to do it with my limited skills is to just go in a manually exchange the, for example, ny & 'NY'. I'm wondering if theres a way to code with in a loop or something.. Appreciate any help!!

```
ma = ds1[ds1.STATE == 'MA'].sort_values('INCOME_AMT', ascending=False)[['NAME', 'CITY', 'STATE', 'ASSET_AMT',
                                                     'INCOME_AMT','REVENUE_AMT']].head(10)
ny = ds1[ds1.STATE == 'NY'].sort_values('INCOME_AMT', ascending=False)[['NAME', 'CITY', 'STATE', 'ASSET_AMT',
                                                     'INCOME_AMT','REVENUE_AMT']].head(10)

...
merged_state_list = [ma,ny,nj,me,nh,vt,ct,ri,ky,va,In,mi,md,dc,pa,sc,oh,wi,
                     nd,nc,il,mn,de,wv,ia,sd,ne,fl,mo,ca,tx,co,tn,ar,ks,ga,
                     al,az,ut,wa,ok,hi,la,nv,ms,Id,ak,nm,mt,Or,wy]

final_set = pd.concat(merged_state_list)
```

Comment: Hey Jeff, welcome to stack overflow. Questions like these are better suited to codereview, so next time post there: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Yes, make a list of the state codes: codes = [‘MA’, ‘NY’ ... ] and then extract your ds1[ds1.STATE ... code into its own function and make a list comprehension merged_state_list = [ ... applying each code to the function.

Comment: I can't edit the title right now because another edit is pending, but it would be better if you had a title that described what it is you want to automate so someone knows what the question is about without having to click through and read (and so once it's answered, someone else can tell if their question is the same as yours from the title). For example, *"Is there a way to automate using the right case for each item in a list?"* -- a good title is specific to the individual question and couldn't be applied to any other.

Comment: btw you wouldn’t be able to create some of those variables, eg ‘in’ and ‘or’ since these are keywords.

Answer (score 1):

For strings there are .upper() and .lower() methods that might help.

For example:

```
 s = "hello"
 s.upper()
 >> 'HELLO'
```

You can always call the .upper() or the .lower() in a for loop. For example:

```
 uppercase_states = []
 for state in merged_state_list.upper():
      uppercase_states.append(state)

 pd.concat(uppercase_states)
```

In above example I create an empty list called "uppercase_states" then append the states using the for loop.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I’m sorry but I don’t see the relevance of this answer.